# How to map keys to launch URLs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

I'm looking for a way to launch some frequently used URLs in Firefox using short-cut keys. It would be a great time saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts

Then press "+" and add your new shortcut. And just type name and command

For example: [image]

After that you have to press this shortcut and change the keys